# How to change the boolean value of one element when another is clicked in HTML via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, contenteditable, pseudocode

I'm trying to make a list such that each element can be edited by the user, since the list is created by user input. I am just starting to use JavaScript, and am still learning. What can I replace the pseudo-code portion with that would produce the desired effect?

HTML:

```
<li v-for="item in items" contenteditable="false" id="item">{{item}}
    <button id="editButton" contenteditable="false" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
```

JS (pseudo-code):

```
function edit(){
    when "editButton" is clicked{
        "contenteditability" in "item" = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this pseudo code theoretically works like a charm... whatts the problem?

Comment: So the button is in the li? So use the event target to get the button, select the parent, and set the attribute.

Comment: And all the answers assume there is one... You can see it is a template so ids are wrong since there will be multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: I doubt the selected answer actually works.... So you only have one li?

Comment: @epascarello yeah, it just creates a new one everytime the user adds an item. and each item gets its own edit button.

Comment: nevermind it only works for the first item...

Comment: So look at my answer where it looks for the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event to determine what button was clicked and select the parent. Than you can set the attribute

```js
function edit(event) {
  var button = event.target,
    li = button.parentNode;
  li.setAttribute("contentEditable", true)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li contenteditable="false"> AAAAA
    <button contenteditable="false" onclick="edit(event)">Edit</button></li>
  <li contenteditable="false"> BBBBB
    <button contenteditable="false" onclick="edit(event)">Edit</button></li>
  <li contenteditable="false"> CCCCC
    <button contenteditable="false" onclick="edit(event)">Edit</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function edit(){
   $("#item").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
}
```

Comment: I think you're mixing jquery with plain javascript... `setAttribute` should be `attr`

Comment: you just try with this it will work... $("#item").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
function edit() {
    document.getElementById('item').setAttribute('contentEditable','true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
function edit(){
   document.getElementById('item').setAttribute('contenteditable',true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" contenteditable="false" id="item>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" id="editButton" contenteditable="false">
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#editButton').on('click', function(){
        $('#item').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        // or
        // $('#item').prop('contenteditable', true);
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

hope this helps you